# List of tuples to map on Erlang

Tags: erlang

I have a list of tuples like this:`[{key,val},{key2,val2}...]`  I want to be able to convert it into a map:

`#{key=>val, key2=>val2 ......}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `from_list` function from [the maps module](http://erlang.org/doc/man/maps.html#from_list-1):

```
maps:from_list(Yourlist).
```

Answer (score 2):

And if Hendri's solution is too simple for you, then you can do this:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).

create_map(List_Of_Key_Val_Tuples) ->
    create_map(List_Of_Key_Val_Tuples, #{}).

create_map([], Acc) ->
    Acc;
create_map([{Key, Val} | Tail], Acc) ->
    create_map(Tail, Acc#{Key => Val}).
```

In the shell:

```
11> c(my).                                                                
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

12> my:create_map([{a, 10}, {"hello", hi}, {fun(X) -> X+2 end, add_two}]).
#{a => 10,#Fun<erl_eval.6.99386804> => add_two,"hello" => hi}
```